# Minidump unit test doesn't return true

Tags: c++, google-breakpad

I have been trying to run this [unittest](https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/browse/trunk/src/client/minidump_file_writer_unittest.cc?r=1018) from Google breakpad for minidumps. Now on line 165, it compares the dump written to /temp/ with expected values that are hardcoded. Here, instead of returning true, the `ASSERT` statement fails.

```
ASSERT_EQ(memcmp(buffer, expected, expected_byte_count), 0);
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

The `ASSERT_EQ` fails because `memcmp(buffer, expected, expected_byte_count)` indicates a difference in the contents from `buffer` and `expected`.

Did you note there is an `#if defined(__BIG_ENDIAN__)` used to select the expected values?
Did you try un-/providing it alternately?